# iPhone 5 app running on iPad reports height 480

Tags: ipad, ios7, ios8

NSLog( @"height %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height) reports 568 on iPhone 5 (iOS 7.1.2), but 480 on iPad Retina (iOS 8.0.2).  How can I get it to report (and run!) as 568 on iPad (iPhone emulation)?  Thanks for helping a newbie.

Edit: It comes up in 2x on iPad; can I force it to 1x?

Comment: the iPad currently mimics the 3.5" screen for iPhone apps.

Answer (score 0):

Was a duplicate, found answers: Can't be done, no.